# Access process.env.VARIALBE in Docker image on Heroku

Tags: docker, vue.js, heroku

I'm having difficulty getting my environment variables from: Heroku -> Docker Image -> Vue
I've defined my Heroku config variables through the settings tab. I'm building the docker image on Bitbucket. I'm deploying to Heroku from Octopus deploy using the docker image previously built, but the process.env.variable is always undefined. I've tried using:

```
configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
          new Dotenv({
            systemvars: true
          })
        ]
      }
```

I've tried using VUE_APP_Variable as the naming convention.
Any help on how to pass these environment variables through would be a big help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the Vue.js documentation, only `NODE_ENV`, `BASE_URL`, and variables that start with `VUE_APP_` will be statically embedded into the client bundle. This is to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name.

Try setting the environment variable `VUE_APP_HELLO_WORLD`, and accessing it with `process.env.VUE_APP_HELLO_WORLD`.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried VUE_APP_VAR as well, I've updated the question to reflect this.